# Making use of "ActiveLink" component in NextJS

Tags: next.js, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I am now reading this page:
https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/use-router
and it contains this chunk of code.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

function ActiveLink({ children, href }) {
  const router = useRouter()
  const style = {
    marginRight: 10,
    color: router.asPath === href ? 'red' : 'black',
  }

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    router.push(href)
  }

  return (
    <a href={href} onClick={handleClick} style={style}>
      {children}
    </a>
  )
}

export default ActiveLink
```

What I want is some sample code that shows how to use this *ActiveLink* component.

Is there some site or blog on the net where I could find that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can test and render this reusable react component online in a simple nextjs [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nextjs-5tlgz) or in your local machine like this :

```js
<ActiveLink href="/link-url">Link Label</ActiveLink>
```

Here is an [article](https://welearncode.com/use-children-react/) about how to render react components in general .

Comment: This is incorrect; You can't put the label inside the component, it's passed as a prop (see answer above).

Answer (score 0):

```
"use client";
 
import Link from "next/link";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";
 
import { cn } from "~/utils/cn";
 
interface Props extends React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof Link> {
  className?: string;
  activeClassName?: string;
}
 
export const ActiveLink = (props: Props) => {
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const isActive = pathname === props.href;
  const activeClassName = props.activeClassName ?? "text-red-500";
 
  return (
    <Link
      {...props}
      className={cn(props.className, isActive && activeClassName)}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**